# Problems installing v8 on OS X (seems like an SVN issue of some sort?)

Tags: macos, v8

Simple `brew install v8` command is giving me the following results.

```
Warning: Your Xcode (5.0.2) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 5.1.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
==> Downloading https://github.com/v8/v8/archive/3.21.17.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/v8-3.21.17.tar.gz
==> Checking out http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (http://gyp.googlecode.com)
Error: Failed to download resource "v8--gyp"
Failure while executing: svn checkout -q --force http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk /Library/Caches/Homebrew/v8--gyp--svn -r 1685
```

Unable to decipher the problem here.  Any information at this point would really help.

Comment: well *something's* out of date...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this! Seems to be an issue with AnyConnect.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113717/svn-cant-co-source-code

I ran `sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/websecurity_uninstall.sh` and voila

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same probleme, but I found another solution.

Simply reinstalling svn :

```
brew install svn
```

Removing old version :

```
rm /usr/local/bin/svnversion
```

Recreate link :

```
brew link subversion
```

And then install v8

```
brew install v8
```

Answer (score 0):

I got yet another solution: my xcode installation was brand new and I never accepted the terms and conditions. Just try to execute $ svn and the terms and conditions of xcode will prompt